# Multidimensional Array with different types in java

Tags: java

I want to store a data structure thats a table with one column Strings and another column of Ints.

```
List<Entry<String, Integer>> li = new LinkedList<Entry<String, Integer>>();
```

would do the job for a list but I would rather have the performance of and need the memory of an array.

I tried

```
Entry<String, Integer>[]  = new Entry<String, Integer>[10];
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Is Entry the right datatype to use?

Comment: Are either the Strings or Integers unique by definition for your problem? If so, a Dictionary might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Marcelo: did you mean a `Map`?

Comment: Are you sure performance will be an issue? What kind of operations are you performing?

Comment: Linked lists and arrays have very different performance characteristics. However you can have ArrayList which is an linked list backed by an array.

Comment: @hhafez You mean a List backed by and array...

Comment: When it comes to performance I'm interested in low amount of memory.
We will have to store a lot of those arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need an array of generic types, you can do this:

```
Entry<String, Integer>[] array = new Entry[10];
```

It gives you a compilation warning though. You can read more about it here:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Wildcards-Arrays-and-Generics-in-Java/2/

Comment: It doesn't compile because it's missing the variable name. But the compiler will still warn you about the unchecked conversion to Entry<String, Integer> even if you add the variable name.

Comment: Is there a way to do this correctly without the compiler complaining?

Comment: Well, you can create a separate class and use it instead of Entry to form the array.

Answer (score 3):

Write a class that represents your tuple and use an array (or a List) of that type. Don't eschew classes, they are your friends!

And what exactly do you mean by "the performance of an array"? Arrays are not necessarily faster than List implementations.

Think of inserting an element at the position 0: A `LinkedList` can do it in O(1). To get the same effect in  an array, you'd have to do an O(n) operation (recreating the array and copying all existing values).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is not working, but:

1. you have to give a name to your array.
2. you can't construct arrays with generic types
3. don't forget `Entry` is an interface.

So, this:

```
Entry<String, Integer>[] = new Entry<String, Integer>[10];
```

Should be this:

```
Entry<String, Integer>[] entries = new Entry[10];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just use ArrayList, shouldn't be much difference in performance compared to a plain array.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
List<Entry<String, Integer>> li = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>();
```